# Compatibility with IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm having trouble getting my website to work with IE6.

This is my first attempt at website design, so I literally have no experience and everything I learned, I learned in the last three to four days.

This is my website as a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgete/

I have it hosted on my personal computer (HORRIBLE internet): `http://41.238.112.237/`

I'd recommend visiting the one on my personal computer to see it with pictures. But if it's not responding, don't be surprised.

It runs fine on FF6 and IE9. I tried it on IE6 and it turned out looking like a giant pool of orange.

What should I keep an eye out for when I'm trying to develop a website?

Comment: Supporting IE6? Does that still exist?

Comment: Do you really need to support IE6?  It's officially dead and a lot less than 5% still use it.  Trust me, if somebody is using IE6, most websites will look very different to them.

Comment: Ok, IE6 bashing aside... is there a specific programming question here?  _"What should I keep an eye out for when I'm trying to develop a website?"_ is just so painfully vague.

Comment: Having problems with any version of IE is normal and expected. IE6 does not work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE9 and none of them work like the other far more modern browsers.

Comment: Imagine there are people in the world that don't be able to buy new hard+software, they visit the web with machines running 10 year old software. 5% is still more than all users of safari or opera. I'm not sure if it is the job of a web-developer to tell the users what they have to use, it's the job of companies when they like to sell their stuff. Why do you think IE9 cannot run under XP? Impossible or do they like to sell Win7 ? Win7 will not run on a 10years old machine, so they have to buy a new PC too.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you have a very specific reason for supporting IE6, just drop it. Seriously - microsoft even has a nice little campaign about it's demise. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

To make my answer a little more specific though, when *I* design a site, I try and take into account the audience. For instance, a real estate site that I developed works in IE7+, with a note to IE6 users that they really should upgrade (usage on the old site was about 1-3%, so it was an acceptable thing to do). On the tech-motivated site that I work on for my job, we only support IE8+ - a majority of our users don't even use IE technology, so pushing that up a bit has no major drawbacks.

You can use sites like this: http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1 to find browser share if you're doing a new site that is for people across the board, but.. don't bother with IE6 unless you're doing something for the Chinese it seems :) (based off of microsoft's site)

Comment: also http://theie9countdown.com/, http://theie8countdown.com/ and http://theie7countdown.com/, community efforts to take up microsofts cause at tracking the end of bad browsers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to design the page for IE6 too, you should take a look at this [CSS-compatibilty-list](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

I guess the major problem currently is the use of the display-property "inline-block" for the navigation-items.

**inline-block** is not supported by IE6.

A workaround may be the use of `display:block` together with a setting of `float:left`